# Can't use wxPython in virtualenv?

Tags: python, wxpython, virtualenv

I made a simple wxPython script that simply shows a window. When I run it in my normal python 2.7.3 with wxPython (`import wx`), it works fine. But when I run it in a virtualenv, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/student/Desktop/text.py", line 3, in <module>
    class mainWindow(wx.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

Why is this? I have wx installed (`./pip install wx` in my virtualenv's bin folder)

Comment: does it say INSTALLEd if you run "pip search wxPython" from your virtualenv?

Comment: @RickardZachrisson the library is `wx`, not `wxPython`. `pip search wx` gave me a lot of text, but running `import wx` doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I that that these steps worked for me a while ago...

[wxpython in a virtualenv](http://codersbuffet.blogspot.com/2009/09/wxpython-in-virtualenv.html)

Comment: I don't want to (can't) build if from source. The reason I'm using a virtualenv is because I don't have root.

Comment: These also don't work for me anymore.  Get an error at step 6

Comment: This solution is no longer valid.  The instructions link to a patch which does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

(Im a python noob) I would coment here how I resolve to make wx work in a virtual env, tested on windows.

First you create your virtualenv (I did mine inside the project's directory)

```
virtualenv env
```

Then, go to the env\Lib\site-packages folder, and create a file there named wx.pth (name does not matter, only matters file extention)

Open the wx.pth file and edit it so it points to your wx-X.X-msw, where X.X is your wx version number. Mine is 3.0 (july 2014). it should be somethind like this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw
```

activate your virtualenv. then open your python shell, and try running `import wx; app = wx.App()` if you do not get any nasty messages, then you should be all set.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

For others, here is what worked for me:

On Mac OSX I installed wxpython with Homebrew using:

```
brew install wxpython
```

Change into your virtualenv site-packages directory:

```
cd /venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

then link the wx.pth

```
ln -s /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx.pth wx.pth
```

and then link the wx-3.0-osx_cocoa directory:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa wx-3.0-osx_cocoa
```

Answer (score 2):

[`wx` on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wx/) is a garbage module that has one trivial function.  Unfortunately someone acquired the name for their "first python module" which has [confused](http://sourceforge.net/p/pypi/support-requests/191/) and [irritated](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issue/62/please-delete-or-rename-the-wx-package) many people.

The string you give `import` and `pip install` can thus obviously be different, e.g. `import PIL` and `pip install pillow`, or nearly every Django plugin.  Here, you want to **`pip install wxpython`**

On Ubuntu installing wxPython can be a bit of a pain, so I would suggest installing it using `apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8` then (if your venv has `--no-site-packages`) symlinking the global library folder into the virtualenv's folder a la:

```
nick@cody:~/sandbox/lib/python2.7/site-packages
$ ls -lhtr wx*
... wx.pth -> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx.pth
... wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode -> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Windows virtualenv...

First, go here to get the wheel binaries of wxpython that matches your system http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython

Now in your virtualenv command prompt, make sure you have wheel

```
>pip install wheel
```

Then install wxpython common

```
>pip install wxPython_common-3.0.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Finally install wxpython itself

```
>pip install wxPython-3.0.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Now in the virtualenv python interpreter, check to see if installation was successful by making and running an example

```
>python
...
>>> import wx
>>> app = wx.App(False)
>>> frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Running from virtualenv!")
>>> frame.Show(True)
>>> app.MainLoop()
```

If a window appears and no error occurs, then you're all good :)